# WARNING: Mac address to reach destination not found when send ipv6 packet

Tags: scapy

when try to send an ipv6 packet i get

> WARNING: Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast.
> Finished sending 1 packets

when i send a packet to specific destination using ipv6 as following:

```
syn = IPv6(dst=destination,src=source) / TCP(sport=555,dport=80,flags="S")
syn_ack = sr1(syn,timeout=11)
```

this happend if i use the ipv6 while on ipv4 i dont see this issue

scapy version :2.4.3
platform: windows server 2019

Comment: does your machine supports ipv6?

Comment: yes and i can ping using ipv6